# Disable user intervention until password entered (not logout)

Tags: 18.04, password, security, lock-screen, input

I'm looking for an option to turn user input off (so to say enable read-only mode) leaving the same picture on screen without logging out from the system, but requiring password to be entered to continue doing something.

For example, I want to turn on a movie and then lock the system against any action. So if I need to leave the room my friends wouldn't be able to do anything with my laptop, just watch the movie till the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Force logout on program close**

You could run your video player with a command like this:

```
smplayer && gnome-screensaver-command -l
```

And then if the player is closed, it will log you out. The && means "execute following function AFTER preceding function is FINISHED".

However, if the player window is simply unfocused and not closed, the logout command will not run. However, this can be fixed with a little scripting to tell the video player to quit on unfocus.

**Kill video player when it is unfocused**

Per this post: [How to execute a command on window focus/unfocus?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/256713/how-to-execute-a-command-on-window-focus-unfocus) you can write a script that will kill your application and/or log out when video player is unfocused.

So, if you run smplayer, then run the following script from the command line, this will log out if SMPlayer looses focus.

First install the needed utils:

```
sudo apt install xdotool wmctrl gnome-screensaver
```

Then put this in a file somewhere, for this example we will call it "be_nice":

```
nano be_nice
```

Paste this in and save:

```
#!/bin/bash

wmctrl -a SMPlayer

while [ true ]
do
  FocusApp=`xdotool getwindowfocus getwindowname`
  if [[ "$FocusApp" != *"SMPlayer"* ]]; then
        killall smplayer
        gnome-screensaver-command -l & break
  fi
done
```

Make it executible:

```
chmod 755 be_nice
```

Now open a video in SMPlayer, then run be_nice from the command line:

```
./be_nice
```

This will bring SMPlayer into focus, and if it leaves focus, will lock the screen. Only problem is 'fullscreen' mode doesn't work as the xdotool can't find the name of a full screen window.

**Log in as guest user**

A final option would be to use the guest or a separate user account when you are letting your friends you don't trust use your computer.

**Just looking to Lock the Screen?**

Power menu in upper right corner of screen. Open that and click the lock, bottom middle of the window that opens up.

[image: Lock Screen]

Comment: okay, you're right, I'm logged in. Seems I didn't ask my question 100% correct, I would like to be logged in, and leave the same screen which was on the screen. Imagine situation, that I want to turn on the movie and then lock the system against any action. So if I need to leave the room my friends wouldn't be able to do anything with my laptop, just watch the movie till the end. Hope this explanation is better, than I wrote in a question before

Comment: no worries... once you have `10 rep ( i think ) you will be able to upvote. in the meantime, welcome to the community! let us know if you have any more questions.... also, we can go through and delete all "conversational" comments to clean this page up